# Questions colored with favorite tags too light?

Tags: discussion, design

I realize this might be a contrast thing, but I think the questions that are colored based on favorite tags (at least I think that's how it's decided) could be a couple shades darker at least:

[image: favorite tag questions]

This really depends on how I'm looking at it (laptop screen), but even at the 'best' angle I think it could do with some darkening.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @jcolebrand's suggestion, I changed it from `rgb(255,245,222)` to `rgb(255,235,175)` and found it better. May not be perfect, but here's a screenshot:

[image: darker version]

Comment: Yeah, that's the right way to describe the selection of those. Are you familiar with CSS and your browser developer tools enough to look for a more appropriate color?

Comment: @jcolebrand updated with possible suggestion

Comment: Had the same question, but found this problem on more SE sites, so I [asked it again, on SO.meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127663/162730)

Comment: Can you share how to do this please?  I'm running Firefox 29.0.1

Comment: This question is unanswered yet. @Derek Downey, it seems that you have an answers, can you publish it here?